# Save contents of apply() to CSV

Tags: r, csv, matrix, frequency

I have a sample data below:

```
library(prodlim)

NUM <- 100
dat1 <- SimSurv(NUM)
dat1$time <- sample(24:160,NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X3 <- sample(0:1,NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X4 <- sample(0:9,NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X5 <- sample(c("a","b","c"),NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X6 <- sample(c("was","que","koa","sim","sol"),NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X7 <- sample(1:99,NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X8 <- sample(1:200,NUM,rep=TRUE)

attach(dat1)
```

I have found a neat line of code that provides all the necessary frequencies a simple `summary(dataset)` can't do in one firing in the question "[*Loop through a .csv file in R, computing relative frequencies?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3401372/3119058)":

```
freq <- apply(X = dat1, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {summary(factor(x))})
```

My question is how can I extract each variable frequency so that I can save them in a CSV file in one command?

Commands `freq[1:1]` to `freq[n:n]` do the job but it is tedious to edit each for printing plus the output in the console needs further text editing.

Comment: If you want a different csv output for each variable you can use sapply(seq(freq) , function(z) write.csv(freq[[z]] , paste0("fileout",z,".csv")))

Comment: Thanks but how do I increase the length of files to be written into the CSV's? Some of my variables have been cut into `Others XXXXX` and I want to exhaust all variable values.

Comment: How do I set the name of each CSV to the variable name?

Comment: sorry (late here) i don't understand. What do you mean 'increase the files' - the number of individual variable summaries (produced in your apply call) will be written to .csv. also what do you mean 'Others XXXXX;.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that other variable values inside the CSV's are cut into the name `Others` and the frequencies of the unexhausted values.

Comment: For the .csv file names use paste0(names(freq[z]),".csv") in the write.csv call

Comment: Found it, I should do `summary(mydata, maxsum=Inf)` to exhaust all variable values from [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-January/265034.html).

Comment: ah ok got you now - nice find

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [@user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650), I managed to solve my problem.

```
freq <- apply(X = dat1, MARGIN = 2, 
  FUN = function(x) {
    summary(factor(x), , maxsum=Inf))
    # maxsum=Inf will prevent truncation of value frequencies
})

sapply(seq(freq), 
  function(z) write.csv(
    freq[z], 
    paste0("path/to/folder/",names(freq[z]),".csv") 
  )
)
```

- `maxsum=Inf` from the thread "[*`summary(list)` is awesome, but I want more than summary*](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-January/265034.html)" prevents truncation of summary value frequencies.
- `sapply()` c/o [@user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) to save each frequency into a separate CSV file with the variable name as filename.

Comment: You're not using the return value of `sapply`.  In that case, I would just use a `for` loop.